# Функция для заливки ячейки выбранным цветом

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Суть в том, чтобы можно было выбрать цвет из имеющихся ячеек и закрасить этим цветом любую ячейку из таблицы.

```css
.board {
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.board td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.board td:hover {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<table class="board">
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx0y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx1y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx2y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx3y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx4y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx5y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx6y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx7y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx8y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx9y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y9"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="board">
  <tr>
    <td id="color1" style="background-color:#FFCC33"></td>
    <td id="color2" style="background-color:#FF3300"></td>
    <td id="color3" style="background-color:#CC00FF"></td>
    <td id="color4" style="background-color:#3300CC"></td>
    <td id="color5" style="background-color:#00CCFF"></td>
    <td id="color6" style="background-color:#66CC00"></td>
    <td id="color7" style="background-color:#660000"></td>
    <td id="color8" style="background-color:#000000"></td>
    <td id="color9" style="background-color:#999999"></td>
    <td id="color10" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: и в чем прболема заключается ваша? заведите переменную, которая будет хранить цвет. Когда кликаете в квадрат со цветом, заполняете эту переменную, когда кликаете в пустые клетки берите значение из переменной и устаналивайте его в фон.

Comment: нужны 2 функции?

Comment: просто с реализацией трудновато сообразаить

Comment: var color = document.getElemntById(idColor);

Comment: примерно так ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного `css` изменил

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.board-colors td')

  colors.forEach(td => td.addEventListener('click', e => {
    colors.forEach(t => t.classList.remove('selected-color'))
    e.target.classList.add('selected-color')
  }))

  document.querySelectorAll('.board td').forEach(td => td.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const selected = document.querySelector('.board-colors td.selected-color')
    if (selected)
      paintCell(e.target.id, selected.style.backgroundColor)
  }))
})

const paintCell = (cellId, color) =>
  document.getElementById(cellId).style.backgroundColor = color
```

```css
.board,
.board-colors {
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.board td,
.board-colors td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.board td:hover,
.board-colors td:hover,
.selected-color {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<table class="board">
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx0y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx0y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx1y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx1y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx2y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx2y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx3y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx3y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx4y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx4y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx5y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx5y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx6y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx6y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx7y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx7y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx8y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx8y9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cellx9y0"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y1"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y2"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y3"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y4"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y5"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y6"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y7"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y8"></td>
    <td id="cellx9y9"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="board-colors">
  <tr>
    <td id="color1" style="background-color:#FFCC33"></td>
    <td id="color2" style="background-color:#FF3300"></td>
    <td id="color3" style="background-color:#CC00FF"></td>
    <td id="color4" style="background-color:#3300CC"></td>
    <td id="color5" style="background-color:#00CCFF"></td>
    <td id="color6" style="background-color:#66CC00"></td>
    <td id="color7" style="background-color:#660000"></td>
    <td id="color8" style="background-color:#000000"></td>
    <td id="color9" style="background-color:#999999"></td>
    <td id="color10" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: нужно используя функцию

Comment: Создать функцию по следующим требованиям:
Входящие параметры: идентификатор клетки и идентификатор цвета из палитры
Результат действия функции:  указанная клетка должна покраситься в указанный цвет

Comment: куда вставлять 1ый кусок вашего кода ?

Comment: где-то нужно вызывать её?

Comment: или передавать какие-то параметры ?

Comment: код вставлять в такую структуру : `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> { тут код })`

Comment: в моем ответе полностью рабочий вариант, сядьте разберитесь, как оно работает

Comment: можете весь код прислать, который написан в тегах <script> </script> . Вставил ваш код в теги скрипт и не работает.

Comment: при этом создав функцию, как Вы и говорили

Comment: а `css`, разметка ? туда тоже изминения внесены ?

Comment: в точности, как у Вас

Comment: я толькочто руками создал новый хтмл файл, закинул туда все ето дело и о чудо, оно работает ) что-то вы явно не так скопировали или не туда вставили

Comment: всё на своих местах вроде бы(1ый блок кода в тегах скрипт)css в style и таблица

Comment: таблица в body.

Comment: всё заработало, спасибо за терпение.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю чем Вам не угодил код предыдущего оратора) Но вот Вам функция и её вызов несколько раз для примера:

```js
function fill(idCell, idColor) {
  var cont = document.getElementById(idCell);
  var contColor = document.getElementById(idColor);
  cont.style.backgroundColor = contColor.style.backgroundColor;
}

fill('cellx4y4', 'color2');
fill('cellx3y1', 'color5');
fill('cellx5y6', 'color6');
fill('cellx9y4', 'color3');
fill('cellx9y1', 'color1');
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.board{margin:100px auto;}
.board td{width:50px;height:50px;border: 1px solid #ccc;}
.board td:hover{border: 1px solid #666; box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
</style>
<script>

  
  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="board">
<tr>
<td id="cellx0y0"></td>
<td id="cellx0y1"></td>
<td id="cellx0y2"></td>
<td id="cellx0y3"></td>
<td id="cellx0y4"></td>
<td id="cellx0y5"></td>
<td id="cellx0y6"></td>
<td id="cellx0y7"></td>
<td id="cellx0y8"></td>
<td id="cellx0y9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="cellx1y0"></td>
<td id="cellx1y1"></td>
<td id="cellx1y2"></td>
<td id="cellx1y3"></td>
<td id="cellx1y4"></td>
<td id="cellx1y5"></td>
<td id="cellx1y6"></td>
<td id="cellx1y7"></td>
<td id="cellx1y8"></td>
<td id="cellx1y9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="cellx2y0"></td>
<td id="cellx2y1"></td>
<td id="cellx2y2"></td>
<td id="cellx2y3"></td>
<td id="cellx2y4"></td>
<td id="cellx2y5"></td>
<td id="cellx2y6"></td>
<td id="cellx2y7"></td>
<td id="cellx2y8"></td>
<td id="cellx2y9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="cellx3y0"></td>
<td id="cellx3y1"></td>
<td id="cellx3y2"></td>
<td id="cellx3y3"></td>
<td id="cellx3y4"></td>
<td id="cellx3y5"></td>
<td id="cellx3y6"></td>
<td id="cellx3y7"></td>
<td id="cellx3y8"></td>
<td id="cellx3y9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="cellx4y0"></td>
<td id="cellx4y1"></td>
<td id="cellx4y2"></td>
<td id="cellx4y3"></td>
<td id="cellx4y4"></td>
<td id="cellx4y5"></td>
<td id="cellx4y6"></td>
<td id="cellx4y7"></td>
<td id="cellx4y8"></td>
<td id="cellx4y9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="cellx5y0"></td>
<td id="cellx5y1"></td>
<td id="cellx5y2"></td>
<td id="cellx5y3"></td>
<td id="cellx5y4"></td>
<td id="cellx5y5"></td>
<td id="cellx5y6"></td>
<td id="cellx5y7"></td>
<td id="cellx5y8"></td>
<td id="cellx5y9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="cellx6y0"></td>
<td id="cellx6y1"></td>
<td id="cellx6y2"></td>
<td id="cellx6y3"></td>
<td id="cellx6y4"></td>
<td id="cellx6y5"></td>
<td id="cellx6y6"></td>
<td id="cellx6y7"></td>
<td id="cellx6y8"></td>
<td id="cellx6y9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="cellx7y0"></td>
<td id="cellx7y1"></td>
<td id="cellx7y2"></td>
<td id="cellx7y3"></td>
<td id="cellx7y4"></td>
<td id="cellx7y5"></td>
<td id="cellx7y6"></td>
<td id="cellx7y7"></td>
<td id="cellx7y8"></td>
<td id="cellx7y9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="cellx8y0"></td>
<td id="cellx8y1"></td>
<td id="cellx8y2"></td>
<td id="cellx8y3"></td>
<td id="cellx8y4"></td>
<td id="cellx8y5"></td>
<td id="cellx8y6"></td>
<td id="cellx8y7"></td>
<td id="cellx8y8"></td>
<td id="cellx8y9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="cellx9y0"></td>
<td id="cellx9y1"></td>
<td id="cellx9y2"></td>
<td id="cellx9y3"></td>
<td id="cellx9y4"></td>
<td id="cellx9y5"></td>
<td id="cellx9y6"></td>
<td id="cellx9y7"></td>
<td id="cellx9y8"></td>
<td id="cellx9y9"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="board">
<tr>
<td id="color1" style="background-color:#FFCC33"></td>
<td id="color2" style="background-color:#FF3300"></td>
<td id="color3" style="background-color:#CC00FF"></td>
<td id="color4" style="background-color:#3300CC"></td>
<td id="color5" style="background-color:#00CCFF"></td>
<td id="color6" style="background-color:#66CC00"></td>
<td id="color7" style="background-color:#660000"></td>
<td id="color8" style="background-color:#000000"></td>
<td id="color9" style="background-color:#999999"></td>
<td id="color10" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: куда вставлять 1ую часть кода из ответа предыдущего пользователя ?  просто в script не работает